# How to fix get request and response with whole html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, axios

I'm new to react, redux and all the other stuff and I am struggling with some problems. My first problem is that I receive from an axios "get" request as a response my whole side. (I think my webpack makes some trouble)  The second problem is that my Axios function will fail with the error "this.props.getBranch is not a function".

I have tried to fix the problems and searched for a while without a solution... So it would be great if you could help me.

**my code**
Multistep Form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import RiskDetails from "./Step1/RiskDetails";
import { getBranch } from "../../actions/riskActions";

class RiskForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1,
      risikoName: "",
      risikoBereich: "",
      risikoKlasse: "",
      branche: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  nextStep() {
    let step = this.state.step;
    this.setState({ step: step + 1 });
  }

  prevStep() {
    let step = this.state.step;
    this.setState({ step: step - 1 });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { risikoName, risikoBereich, risikoKlasse, branche } = this.state;
    const values = { risikoName, risikoBereich, risikoKlasse, branche };
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <RiskDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            values={values}
            getBranch={getBranch}
          />
        );
    }
  }
}

RiskForm.propTypes = {
  getBranch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  state => {
    return {};
  },
  { getBranch }
)(RiskForm);
```

my riskDetails

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Grid, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class RiskDetails extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getBranch().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={8}>
            <Form>
              <Form.Select
                fluid
                label={value.branch}
                //options={this.state.branch}
                placeholder={value.branch}
              />
            </Form>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

RiskDetails.propTypes = {
  getBranch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default RiskDetails;
```

my actions

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_BRANCH } from "./types";

export function createRisk(event) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post("/api/risk", event);
  };
}

export function fetchRiskDetails(risk) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_BRANCH,
    risk
  };
}

export function getBranch() {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("starting get request")
    return axios.get("/api/risk").then(res => {
      dispatch(fetchRiskDetials(res.data));
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  };
}
```

reducer

```
import { FETCH_BRANCH } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  risk: {}
};

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BRANCH:
      return {
        risk: action.risk
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

server index.js

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

//WEBPACK
import webpack from "webpack";
import webpackMiddleware from "webpack-dev-middleware";
import webpackHotMiddleware from "webpack-hot-middleware";
import wepbackConfig from "../webpack.config.dev";

//IMPORT ALL API ROUTES
import authRoute from "./routes/auth";
import signUpRoute from "./routes/signup";
import companyRoute from "./routes/company";
import riskRoute from "./routes/risk";
import recommendationRoute from "./routes/recommendation";

let app = express();

const compiler = webpack(wepbackConfig);

app.use(
  webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: wepbackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
  })
);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// SET UP YOUR DB FOR THE API
// =============================================================================


var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blubb";

mongoose
  .connect(
    url,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("connected to DB"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
});

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/risk", riskRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("running"));
```

risk part

```
import express from "express";
import {
  validatePostInput,
  validateDeleteInput
} from "../shared/validation/risk";
import Risk from "../models/risk";
import authenticate from "../middleware/authenticate";

let router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("hi form server");
  Risk.find(function(err, risks) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json(risks);
    }
  });
});

//create new risk
router.post("/", authenticate, (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validatePostInput(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  if (isValid) {
    const { risikoName, risikoBereich, risikoKlasse, createdBy } = req.body;
    var newRisk = new Risk({
      risikoName,
      risikoBereich,
      risikoKlasse,
      createdBy
    });

    // save the risk
    newRisk.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      }
      res.json({ success: true });
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
});

//delete risk
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateDeleteInput(req.body);
  if (isValid) {
    const { id } = req.body;
    Risk.remove({ _id: id }, function(err, risk) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      res.json({ success: true });
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
});

export default router;
```

webpack config

```
import path from "path";
import webpack from "webpack";

export default {
  mode: "development",
  entry: [
    "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
    path.join(__dirname, "client/index.js")
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: "/",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "client"),
          path.join(__dirname, "server/shared")
        ],
        loaders: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
        loader: "sass-loader!style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"]
  }
};
```

===EDIT===
Here is my response from a request

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Tool</title>
        <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a problem in your response for sure  - your response should be some json but you get an HTML( probably your current HTML page) - so first all make sure you make a valid request and got some json as your response

Comment: Servers that serve SPAs (single page applications) are generally configured to redirect to `/` for any resource that is not available (`404`). That means if the URL is not reachable for some reason the server returns what you are referring to as _the whole site_ (which is probably your index.html file). You should check your server logs to determine if the URL is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I could fix my problem first problem with bayus answer

Answer (score 0):

**First,** the reason why you always get whole HTML page, I guess it caused by routing management. Looks like the part when you using asterisk/wild card in your route as follows:

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
});
```

Looks it will handle all requests, so router describe after that will never get reached. Try to change it with:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
});
```

If you really need it to have `/*` put another one at very last line of router declaration.

**2nd**:

You call `props` inside `componentWillMount()`, which usually props not yet available at that lifecycle. Even usually it still not available in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle. Based on some articles I read, `componentWillMount()` is deprecated in current React version. I suggest you to not using it. There are 2 ways to solve this kind of problem I can recommend you as follow:

1. componentDidMount() method

Using `componentDidMount()` lifecycle. In this method, you should put `setTimeout()` to give the component a time to receive props.

```
componentDidMount() {

    setTimeout(()=>{

      this.props.getBranch().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    },
    100);//Try with 0 first ( not put this parameter ), if it is not works, try to increase by 100, 200 etc.
}
```

2. getDerivedStateFromProps() method

The old way is using `componentWillRecieveProps()`, but because it is deprecated, I recommend to use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` instead. In this life cycle phase, it doesn't need `setTimeout()` trick. Because props should already available.

For your reference, here is good article about deprecated React Livecycles: https://hackernoon.com/problematic-react-lifecycle-methods-are-going-away-in-react-17-4216acc7d58b

**==== UPDATE Jan 22 '19  ======**

Just a suggestion, usually we can just call redux actions directly to the component instead passing them as props. So you can clean up `RiskForm` component from Redux wiring as follow:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { connect } from "react-redux"; //!!! move connect() inside RiskDetails instead
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import RiskDetails from "./Step1/RiskDetails";
// import { getBranch } from "../../actions/riskActions"; //!!!!Move this to RiskDetails component

class RiskForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1,
      risikoName: "",
      risikoBereich: "",
      risikoKlasse: "",
      branche: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  nextStep() {
    let step = this.state.step;
    this.setState({ step: step + 1 });
  }

  prevStep() {
    let step = this.state.step;
    this.setState({ step: step - 1 });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { risikoName, risikoBereich, risikoKlasse, branche } = this.state;
    const values = { risikoName, risikoBereich, risikoKlasse, branche };
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <RiskDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            values={values}
            // getBranch={getBranch}//!!! Don't need this props, import inside RiskDetails directly
          />
        );
    }
  }
}

RiskForm.propTypes = {
  getBranch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

/*
export default connect(
  state => {
    return {};
  },
  { getBranch }
)(RiskForm);*/

export default RiskForm;//You can remove connect() and leave this as dumb component
```

Then make your `RiskDetails` component as Container/smart component as follow ( please pay attention at comments I made with exclamation/'!' ):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';//!!! Import redux here
import { Grid, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getBranch } from "../../actions/riskActions";//!!! Import action creator here

class RiskDetails extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    getBranch().then(res => {//Call the action creator directly instead using props
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={8}>
            <Form>
              <Form.Select
                fluid
                label={value.branch}
                //options={this.state.branch}
                placeholder={value.branch}
              />
            </Form>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

RiskDetails.propTypes = {
  getBranch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null)(RiskDetails);//!!! Connect this component with redux
```

Comment: My first problem is solved! Thanks a lot for your help but the second one is still nit fixed.

Comment: Nice to know you fix first problem. About second one, do you still get error message `this.props.getBranch is not a function` ?

Comment: I made update to suggest change Container/smart component to `RiskDetails` instead `RiskForm`, please check it Hope it helps.